# Null Pointer exception in Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I have some functions, that save data 'Dialog' and 'Message' in realm DB.

```
private void addMessageToDialog(ObservableDialog dialog, DialogMessage dialog_msg) {
        // if i try to use FINDDIALOG - i have NPE errors
        rDialog rDialog  = findDialog(dialog.getChatId());
        realm.beginTransaction();
        rMessage rMessage = constructObjectRMessage(dialog_msg);
        realm.copyToRealm(rMessage);            
        if(rDialog==null) rDialog = constructObjectRDialog(dialog);
        rDialog.getDialogMessages().add(rMessage);
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(rDialog);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
private rDialog constructObjectRDialog(ObservableDialog dialog) {
        try {
            rDialog rDialog = new rDialog();
            rDialog.setChatId(dialog.getChatId());
            rDialog.setCreator(dialog.isCreator());
            rDialog.setNickname(dialog.getNickname());
            rDialog.setAvatarUrl(dialog.getAvatarUrl());
            rDialog.setPartnerOkId(dialog.getPartnerId());
            rDialog.setBanned(dialog.isBanned());

            List<ChatStatus> statusHistory = dialog.getStatusHistory();
            RealmList<rChatStatus> statuses = new RealmList<>();
            for (ChatStatus s : statusHistory) {
                rChatStatus st = constuctorRChatCtatus(s.name());
                realm.copyToRealm(st);
                statuses.add(st);
            }
            rDialog.setStatusHistory(statuses);

            List<DialogMessage> dialogMessages = dialog.getMessages();
            RealmList<rMessage> messages = new RealmList<>();
            for (DialogMessage d : dialogMessages) {
                rMessage m = constructObjectRMessage(d);
                realm.copyToRealm(m);
                messages.add(m);
            }
            rDialog.setDialogMessages(messages);
            return rDialog;
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }


private rDialog findDialog(String chatId) {
        RealmResults<rDialog> d = realm.where(rDialog.class)
            .equalTo("chatId", chatId)
            .findAll();             
        if(d.size()==0) return null;
        return d.first();
    }
```

When i use this code, it works only if i DON't USE `findDialog` (and `realm.where` method, and only use `constructObjectRDialog`).
But when i try to use `findDialog` (in  `addMessageToDialog`) I have NPE error in

```
 rDialog.getDialogMessages().add(rMessage);
```

Why can be such erros?
PS - `rMessage` and `rDialog` are not null (when i check it in debugger)

LOG:

```
02-28 11:43:21.220    6432-6460/com.OkLove.OkLoveDroid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-468
    Process: com.OkLove.OkLoveDroid, PID: 6432
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at io.realm.RealmList.add(RealmList.java:120)
            at com.OkLove.OkLoveDroid.BackgroundTasksHandlers.DbHandler.addMessageToDialog(DbHandler.java:98)
            at com.OkLove.OkLoveDroid.BackgroundTasksHandlers.DbHandler.handleMessage(DbHandler.java:77)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at com.OkLove.OkLoveDroid.BackgroundTasksHandlers.DbHandlerThread.run(DbHandlerThread.java:30)
```

Comment: Post your log from logacat

Comment: @ChristianMelchior , can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that problem was in 'copies of object that have a Realm type' and 'real instance of realm db object', see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/realm-java/lK6Q6zRYTE0

My edited code now looks like:

```
 private void addMessageToDialog(ObservableDialog dialog, DialogMessage dialog_msg) {
        rDialog rDialog  = findDialog(dialog.getChatId());
        rMessage rMessage = constructObjectRMessage(dialog_msg);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        rMessage = realm.copyToRealm(rMessage);
        if(rDialog==null) {
            rDialog = constructObjectRDialog(dialog);
            if(rDialog!=null) rDialog = realm.copyToRealm(rDialog);
            else realm.cancelTransaction();
        } else Log.v(TAG,"dialog is not null");
        rDialog.getDialogMessages().add(rMessage);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

When doing `copyToRealm` - should use return type `rDialog` to edit realm object (but not copy of standalone object)